# NavBar is showing white space at its bottom while i added SeachView as titleView in IOS using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, padding, navigationcontroller

I am having a weird problem with the view designed in xib file using Xcode 9.4.1 . I added the searchBar as the title view to the NavBar the view was showing fine but as i move to the next ViewController the height of the navBar gets minimized a little, it shows a white space at the bottom of navBar and when i move back to the previous View having searchBar as the titleView in navBar the white space exist there as well. I have attached the screenshots as well to get a clear idea 
 [image: here the view is all right with no white space at the bottom of navBar]

[image: this is when i move to the next screen without searchBar it shows white space under navBar][image: here when i return back to the screen with navBar the white is carried here as well]

I am using xib file and adding the navBar programmatically in the View. I have also tried to adjust the height of navBar according to the screen but it didn't worked, can anyone get the idea whats happening around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notes the searchBar , make sure this white space reason. i suspect the reason is tableview's tableHeaderView in the second viewcontroller. Because I have the same experience.

Comment: Hi @stackStevn thanks for the response, can you please explain a little more. I checked the tableView but each View is below the buttons at top on both screens.

Comment: i am not using autolayout and these are xib files, the Xcode version is 9.4.1. secondly if i push the buttons up by setting up their frame for all screen sizes, the buttons get hide after the white padding that appears at bottom of navBar in both screens.

Comment: The system native UISearchBar has undergone a revolution in iOS 11, which has changed from 44 to 56. you can fix it by add follow code **if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        [searchBar.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:44].active = YES;
    }**  . Important: alway make a custom searchBar fix the height chage.

Comment: Great, that is what i was missing, how can i forget that. Thanks @stackStevn :)